# Type mismatch: cannot convert from StringBuilder to String

Tags: java, android

This method returns the source of the given URL.

```
private static String getUrlSource(String url) {
    try {
        URL localUrl = null;
        localUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = localUrl.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        String html;
        StringBuilder ma = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            ma.append(line);
        }
        return ma;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERR",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from StringBuilder to String
```

And two choices:

1. `Change the return type to StringBuilder.`
   But I want it to return a String.
2. `Change type of ma to String.`
   After changing a String has no append() method.

Comment: `return ma.toString();` ???

Comment: As a side note, you might want to `ma.append(line).append(LINE_SEPERATOR)` or your lines will be all garbled like `This is line 1.This is line 2.This is line 3.`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just use

```
return ma.toString();
```

instead of

```
return ma;
```

`ma.toString()` returns the string representation for your StringBuilder.

See [StringBuilder#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString()) for details

As Valeri Atamaniouk suggested in comments, you should also return something in the `catch` block, otherwise you will get a compiler error for `missing return statement`, so editing

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERR",e.getMessage());
}
```

to

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERR",e.getMessage());
    return null; //or maybe return another string
}
```

Would be a good idea.

---

**EDIT**

As Esailija suggested, we have three anti-patterns in this code

```
} catch (Exception e) {           //You should catch the specific exception
    Log.e("ERR",e.getMessage());  //Don't log the exception, throw it and let the caller handle it
    return null;                  //Don't return null if it is unnecessary
}
```

So i think it is better to do something like that:

```
private static String getUrlSource(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL localUrl = null;
    localUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection conn = localUrl.openConnection();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    String html;
    StringBuilder ma = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        ma.append(line);
    }
    return ma.toString();
}
```

And then, when you call it:

```
try {
    String urlSource = getUrlSource("http://www.google.com");
    //process your url source
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    //your url is wrong, do some stuff here
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //I/O operations were interrupted, do some stuff here
}
```

Check these links for further details about Java Anti-Patterns:

- [Java Anti-Patterns](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php)
- [Programming Anti-Patterns](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/programming-antipatterns.html)
- [An Introduction to Antipatterns in Java Applications](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/29162)

Comment: Function must also return a value in case of exception. If you haven't noticed.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Yes they do **sometimes**, but that's outside the scope of the question. It would make a great comment for the OP, though, like my advice on adding line separators.

Comment: swallowing exception, logging it and returning `null` - all 3 antipatterns at the same time. Impressive.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem while converting StringBuilder to String, and i use above point but that's not give correct solution.
using above code output comes like this

```
    String out=ma.toString();
// out=[Ljava.lang.String;@41e633e0
```

After that i find out correct solution.Think is create a new String instant inserted of StringBuilder like this..

```
String out=new String(ma);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

**return ma.toString();**
as you can not directly store stringbuilder variable into a string variable.