# Palindrome Tester in Java

Tags: java

I have a code to test a string of characters to see if they are in palindrome form. I get an error at on the last line saying Stringbuilder cannot be converted to String. I don't understand if I am building a string, how is that not a string.  Also, part of the assignment was to create our own stack class.  Mine is called MyStack, but I am not sure I am calling it anywhere except when I make a new stack.  How do I call MyStack instead of the library stack?

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String line) throws StackException {
    MyStack Stack = new MyStack();
    // initialize loop counters
    int i = 0;
    int n = line.length();

    /* Push all char to a_stack */
    while (i < line.length()){
        char ch = line.charAt(i);
        Stack.push(ch);
        i++;
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while (!Stack.empty()){
        result.append(Stack.pop());
    }
    result.toString();

    return inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(result);
}
```

Comment: A `StringBuilder` isn't a `String`, it's an object that makes a `String`. Saying that a `String` is a `StringBuilder` is like saying that a construction worker is a building because he/she builds a building (sort of). You need to convert it to a `String`. The answer to your second question is "don't name your variables the same name as library classes and follow naming conventions to avoid getting confused"

Comment: `result.toString()` returns a `String`. It doesn't make `result` change type; `result` is still a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type mismatch: cannot convert from StringBuilder to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155800/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-stringbuilder-to-string)

Comment: Ah, ok thank you.  I that that's what I was doing in the line result.toString(); above it, but I guess not. THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `StringBuilder` to `String`

```
return inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
return inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(result.toString());
```

instead of

```
return inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(result);
```

ie, you have to convert [StringBuilder to String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Since [`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) takes a String, and not a StringBuilder, you need to convert the `StringBuilder` to a String for that equality check, also I think you meant `line` not `inputString`

```
return line.equalsIgnoreCase(result.toString());
```